# Expecting SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT country) to return 46 but getting only 1

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

I have a simple function I made in PHP.

It looks for distinct countries in a member database.

There are 46 (counted by hand), but the function is only returning 1.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
function getCountryCount(){
    $construct = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT country) FROM members2";
    $run = mysql_query($construct);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($run);
    return $count;
}
```

Comment: COUNT function gives a single value. That is why num_rows is coming as 1. You need to access the value returned by mysql_query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of rows returned by the query is one. Hence what you are getting is right.

If you are trying to get the count then don't do `$count = mysql_num_rows($run);` instead just return the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the distinct values (and not the count of distinct values) the correct query would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(country) from members2;
```

So if `members2` contains 100 rows with `country` value set to "Australia" and 37 with the value set as "USA", you'd get one result row that says "Australia" and one result row that says "USA".

With your query, you'd get only one result that says "2" as there are 2 distinct countries in the table